# flatten Pyspark Dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe that is coming from an ORC file. The structure of the dataframe is like bellow:

```
df = spark.read.format("orc_path")
df.show()
```

---

| Key | Content |
| --- | --- |
| some_values | {"column1": "value1"} |

(this is just a sample, there are several columns in the Content)

The records are in the content column, I want to filter the dataframe, so I need to flatten the data. How can I retrieve information/column names and values from the Content? I do not want use Pandas!

Answer (score 0):

Try with `from_json` function and you need to define the schema of the json string that's in `content`.

**`Example:`**

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('someval','{"column1": "value1"}')],['key', 'content'])

sch=StructType([StructField("column1",StringType(),True)])

df.withColumn("tmp", from_json(col("content"), sch)).\
  select("key","tmp.*").\
    show(10,False)
#+-------+-------+
#|key    |column1|
#+-------+-------+
#|someval|value1 |
#+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way doing of this (extension to @notNull's answer) is by using `MapType` inside `from_json` function so as to create the key value pairs for columns and rows. Subsequently, you can use `explode` and then `pivot` functions to get the desired result set. Having said that, you'll be able to guess the schema dynamically without actually defining it.
See below for details -

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

df1 = df.select('key', from_json('content', MapType(StringType(), StringType())))

df2 = df1.select('key', explode('entries').alias('cols','rows'))

df2.groupBy('key').pivot('cols').agg(first('rows')).show()

+-------+-------+
|    key|column1|
+-------+-------+
|someval| value1|
+-------+-------+
```

Comment: If the answer helped to solve the problem please check the ✓ symbol next to the answer. Upvote too, if you like.